# Continuous of $\sqrt{z}$ in $\mathbb C$

Tags: complex-analysis

Consider the function $f(z)=\sqrt{z}$, $f:\mathbb C\to \mathbb C$, where by $\sqrt{z}$ we mean the unique $w\in\mathbb C$ such that $z=w^2$ and $0<Re(w)$ if $w\notin(-\infty,0]$ or $w=i\sqrt{-z}$ for $w\in(-\infty,0]$.

I know that $f$ is analytic in every $z$ such that $0<Re(z)$. Is $f$ is continues in every point in $\mathbb C$?

Comment: There isn't a unique such $w$ for negative real $z$.

Comment: Thanks. you right...I fixed it.

Comment: The fact that you have to correct the question to address what happen in the negative reals should give you a hint about the continuity of $f$

Comment: The answer is no, and searching for the words "branch cut" can tell you how we tend to deal with this negative fact.

Comment: Thanks. I still can not find a sequence $(z_n)$ such that $\lim_{n\to\infty} z_n=L$ but $\lim_{n\to\infty}\sqrt{z_n} \neq \sqrt{L}$. You suggest that I should take L to be negative real ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have chosen the branch cut that gives you the following data:

$z = r \mathrm{e}^{i \varphi}, \quad r \ge 0, \quad -\pi < \varphi \le \pi,\quad \sqrt{z} = \sqrt{r} \mathrm{e}^{i \varphi/2}\ $

So, $(r_n,\varphi_n)=(1,\pi-1/n)\to (1,\pi)$ and $\sqrt z_n\to (1,\pi/2).$

And $(r_n,\varphi_n)=(1,-\pi-1/n)\to (1,-\pi)$ and $\sqrt z_n\to (1,-\pi/2).$

But passing to rectangular coordinates, this means that as $z_n\to (-1,0)$ along the arc of the unit circle in the second quadrant of $\mathbb C,$ $\sqrt z_n\to (1,i)$, whereas as $z_n\to (-1,0)$ along the arc of the unit circle in the third quadrant of $\mathbb C,\ \sqrt z_n\to (1,-1).$

This argument works for any $r>0,$ so the root function, with the branch cut you chose, is not continuous on the negative $x-$ axis.